# VHDL and floating point numbers (IEEE754)

Tags: floating-point, vhdl, ieee-754

I am implementing a PRNG in VHDL using LFSRs. LFSR generates uniform distributed numbers, but I need exponential distribution. Therefore I would like to use floating point numbers based on IEEE754 standard, but this can not be synthesized by the Xilinx Synthesis tool. Could you help me out what should I do? Is there any synthesis-ready libraries or VHDL codes out there?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: VHDL-2008 incorporates synthesisable fixed and floating point packages. But I'd first consider what it would take to process one or more LFSRs to convert their output to the distribution you require : it may be more hardware efficient than a floating point solution.

Comment: @BrianDrummond First of all, thank you for the answer. Could you tell me an other way to solve the problem? How do you convert a uniform distribution to exponential without the exponential function (or a fitting function, like polynomial fitting)?

Comment: Not specifically, partly because I can't visualise the distribution you are looking for. But for example, the linear sum of 2 decorrelated uniform distributions gives a triangular distribution; ditto the sum of 10 or more gives a pretty good approx to a Gaussian distribution.

Comment: @BrianDrummond Yes, the Gaussian one is easy if it's based on the Central Limit Theorem, but I don't know any similar tricks for the exponential one. BTW, could you tell me the exact name of the floating point package for VHDL 2008? Is this version of the language supported by Xilinx synth tool? Thank you in advance.

Comment: See http://www.eda.org/fphdl/Float_ug.pdf

Comment: I know the Ziggurat algorithm is popular to transform uniform distribution into at. Wikipedia has description for similar algorithms, may be you will find what you seek: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ziggurat_algorithm https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Non-uniform_random_numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Vivado's IP catalog a float IP can be found. It is connected via AXI-4, but it is fine for me, because I'm using MicroBlaze.